# Dynamically change to portrait mode - SSSP

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, ssp

I am successfully running my application in portrait mode. Thanks for the great documentation here:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/tut20009/index.html

But I have a big issue now. I need to change the orientation dynamically. Do SSSP have any such API for changing the orientation dynamically (just by code).

Any idea/help will be greatly appreciated.

PS- We have 3x LFD TV (DM32D, DM48D, DB32D)